# Google OAuth 2.0 Authentication throwing SocketTimeoutException : Read timeout

Tags: oauth-2.0, google-oauth, google-apps-marketplace, google-oauth-java-client

I am trying to authenticate with Google using OAuth 2.0 for GAMv2 Apps.

```
GoogleCredential.Builder credentialBuilder = new GoogleCredential.Builder();
credentialBuilder.setTransport(httpTransport).setJsonFactory(jsonFactory);
credentialBuilder.setServiceAccountId(serviceAccountId);
credentialBuilder.setServiceAccountPrivateKeyFromP12File(new File(p12FileURL.toURI()));
credentialBuilder.setServiceAccountScopes(scopes);
credentialBuilder.setServiceAccountUser(userEmail);
credential = credentialBuilder.build();
credential.refreshToken();
Oauth2 userInfoService = new Oauth2.Builder(new NetHttpTransport(), new JacksonFactory(), credential).setApplicationName(applicationName).build();
Userinfoplus userInfo = null;

try
{
    userInfo = userInfoService.userinfo().get().execute();
}
catch (IOException e)
{
    logger.error("Exception_Thrown while getting User Info:", e);
}
```

I am using the above code for getting the userInfo and facing the following exception :

```
java.net.SocketTimeoutException: Read timed out
at java.net.SocketInputStream.socketRead0(Native Method)
at java.net.SocketInputStream.read(SocketInputStream.java:129)
at com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.InputRecord.readFully(InputRecord.java:293)
at com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.InputRecord.read(InputRecord.java:331)
at com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.readRecord(SSLSocketImpl.java:798)
at com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.readDataRecord(SSLSocketImpl.java:755)
at com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.AppInputStream.read(AppInputStream.java:75)
at java.io.BufferedInputStream.fill(BufferedInputStream.java:218)
at java.io.BufferedInputStream.read1(BufferedInputStream.java:258)
at java.io.BufferedInputStream.read(BufferedInputStream.java:317)
at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.parseHTTPHeader(HttpClient.java:687)
at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.parseHTTP(HttpClient.java:632)
at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getInputStream(HttpURLConnection.java:1195)
at java.net.HttpURLConnection.getResponseCode(HttpURLConnection.java:379)
at sun.net.www.protocol.https.HttpsURLConnectionImpl.getResponseCode(HttpsURLConnectionImpl.java:318)
at com.google.api.client.http.javanet.NetHttpResponse.<init>(NetHttpResponse.java:36)
at com.google.api.client.http.javanet.NetHttpRequest.execute(NetHttpRequest.java:94)
at com.google.api.client.http.HttpRequest.execute(HttpRequest.java:965)
at com.google.api.client.googleapis.services.AbstractGoogleClientRequest.executeUnparsed(AbstractGoogleClientRequest.java:410)
at com.google.api.client.googleapis.services.AbstractGoogleClientRequest.executeUnparsed(AbstractGoogleClientRequest.java:343)
at com.google.api.client.googleapis.services.AbstractGoogleClientRequest.execute(AbstractGoogleClientRequest.java:460)
```

Until last few days, it was fine. Only in a couple of days now we are facing this issue.
Can anyone help with this issue ?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Are you still seeing this problem? It sounds like an issue with your network.

Comment: @Eric Now its working fine and we are not facing the exception.

Answer (score 0):

you can get instance of HttpRequestInitializer from Oauth2.Builder and pass it as input parameter

`private static HttpRequestInitializer setHttpTimeout(final HttpRequestInitializer requestInitializer) {
      return new HttpRequestInitializer() {
        @Override
        public void initialize(HttpRequest httpRequest) throws IOException {
          requestInitializer.initialize(httpRequest);
          httpRequest.setConnectTimeout(3 * 60000);  // 3 minutes connect timeout
          httpRequest.setReadTimeout(3 * 60000);  // 3 minutes read timeout
        }
      };
  }`